# Maven with Java play 2 framework: Server not starting

Tags: java, maven, playframework-2.0

I have a java play 2 project that i'm trying to run using maven. I added the `play2-maven-plugin` to my `pom.xml`.

When I try to run the following command `mvn clean compile play2:run`, I get the following:

```

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building my_project 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ my_project ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/sergenasr/my_project/target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ my_project ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ my_project ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> play2-maven-plugin:1.0.0-alpha5:run (default-cli) > process-classes @ my_project >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ my_project ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ my_project ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< play2-maven-plugin:1.0.0-alpha5:run (default-cli) < process-classes @ my_project <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- play2-maven-plugin:1.0.0-alpha5:run (default-cli) @ my_project ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 35.640 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-11-01T22:07:17-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/125M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

```

However, I don't see the server running.

Also, note that I can run the server normally using `activator`, then `~run`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the latest `1.0.0-beta5` plugin version.
2. Read [general plugin usage](https://play2-maven-plugin.github.io/play2-maven-plugin/1.0.0-beta5/usage.html) document.
3. Read plugin usage page for Play! Framework version used in your project (there are links on general usage page).